# Creating a certain JSON data structure in Swift

Tags: json, swift

For backend communication, my app requires a method to create a certainly structured JSON, and thats where i struggle.
The created JSON is supposed to look like this:

```
{    
"data": {    
"color":"yellow",    
"size":"big"    
}    
}
```

Serializing a Dictionary with the required Data does not really seem to have the option to format the content properly, my best results look like this:

```
Optional({    
Kategorie = Strassenschaeden;    
PLZ = 46282;    
Strasse = Erftweg;    
Unterkategorie = Schlagloch;    
})
```

I didnt find any helpful weblinks for my problem, and since im new to Swift and its documentation Im kinda stuck at the moment. 
So my questions are:
Whats the preferred data structure for my JSON data (Dictionary/Array) and how do I create a JSON that is well-formated?
Thanks in advance :)

Edit: This is the interesting part of what i have used to achieve my "best result":

```
var data: [String: String] = ["Kategorie": "\(Kategorie)", "Unterkategorie": "\(Unterkategorie)", "Strasse": "\(Strasse)","PLZ": "\(PLZ)"]

self.post(data, url: "http://*************") { (succeeded: Bool, msg: String) -> () in
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success!", message: msg, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay.")

func post(params : Dictionary<String, String>, url : String, postCompleted : (succeeded: Bool, msg: String) -> ()) {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

let JSONData:NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &err)!
var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: &err) as? NSDictionary
println(json)
```

Comment: Did you have a look at NSJSONSerialization? There are already plenty of Q&A about the usage of that class in Swift.

Comment: Yes i did, every option of NSJSONWritingOptions does not fit to my problem, PrettyPrinted for example.

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: Well, from your question it is not clear what you tried and how you got the "best result" (which is no JSON at all).

Comment: @Martin R NSJSONSerialization does not seem to have the options to format a JSON in the way i need it, especially concerning the semicolons and equal signs. Im aware of the fact that its not a valid JSON, even though I achieved it by using NSJSONSerialization. Any tips on options I may have interpreted wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
let JSONData:NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &err)!
var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: &err) as? NSDictionary
```

you are converting the `params` dictionary to JSON data – and then you convert the
JSON data back do a dictionary! What you probably want is to create a *string*
from the JSON data:

```
let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted, error: &err)!
let json = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
println(json)
```

Remarks:

- Properties and variables should have names starting with lower case letters, e.g.
  `jsonData`.
- The explicit type annotation `:NSData` is not needed here, the Swift compiler can
  infer the type automatically.
- The option can be given as `.PrettyPrinted` instead of `NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted`, the compiler infers the enumeration type
  automatically.
- Instead of forced unwrapping with `!` you should use optional binding to check
  for success.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful :) So my data is already in a good format, what i was concerned about was just the println of a Dictionary, right? And any idea how i can exchange the optional() to "data" { ?

Comment: @Raijen: If you look at the definition of `JSONObjectWithData()` then you'll see that it returns `AnyObject?`. The question marks indicates an *optional* which can be `nil` (for "no value") if the function "failed". Unwrapping is one way to "remove the optional", optional binding is another. – There is no way around it: If you want to do serious programming in Swift then you *have to* fully understand what optional are and how the work. It is covered in the official Swift documentation and also in many Q&A here on SO.

Comment: Im gonna read into that, thank you :) Any tips on how to add the word data in front of my JSON? Since its required to use an Array or a Dictionary, i don't really have an idea. Thought that the name of the dictionary i use would be part of the object in my JSON i am converting the dictionary into.

Comment: @Raijen: Well then you have to create a dictionary `[ "data" : params ]` and convert *that* to JSON.

Comment: Thanks again, that did very well! I have created a Dictionary<String,<Dictionary<String, String>>, and now everything is working fine :) Thank you for being so patient with me :)

Answer (score 0):

Just an itch, that no one here recommend [swiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) for working with JSON in Swift.

Try it, you will lose your pain of dealing with JSON.
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

**To Read JSON**

```
let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
let jsonObject = JSON(data: jsonData!)
```

**To Write JSON**

```
let jsonString = jsonObject.rawString()
```

Comment: That's a good library, but irrelevant to this question, which is about _creating_ JSON, not reading it.

Comment: I've updated an explanation on how to read and write JSON. It is good enough to read JSON, right?

Comment: Nice tip, a really good libary :) Even though getting through JSON Serialization has improved my coding skills concerning Swift, so i would recommend other starters to work their way through this itch, because its a very helpful lesson.